Redefine subscript and superscript behaviour for specific commands?
I often create commands with subscripts or superscript, such for example:
\newcommand{\testone}{\mathsf{test}_{1}}
For these specific commands, I would love to be able to redefine the meaning of subscript and exponent, for example with
\testone_2 equal to \mathsf{test}_{1,2} instead of \mathsf{test}_{1}_2 (this kind of situation actually happens a lot with one of my projects).
This is not something that I really need, as there are other possible solutions. For example,
I usually add an optional argument for the command to ensure that \testone[2] gives \mathsf{test}_{1,2}. Nevertheless, in rare cases, this solution can be ugly.
This happens for example when my command use both a subscript and superscript, let's say,
\newcommand{\testtwo}{\mathsf{test}_{2}^{2}} and that I need to add two optional arguments for subscript and superscript. Another problem is that the "optional argument" is taken by superscript/subscript, while I would prefer to use it for something else.
I am thus curious:

Is such a "redefinition" possible? If it is, it seems important that it is only activated if the character following the command is "_" or "^" : I don't want {\testone}_1to use the redefinition of the subscript.
Do you think it would be dirty to use such redefinition?
Do you think there is a more elegant solution than this redefinition?

Thank you for reading me!

That is trivial to do using ltcmd using embellishments.
\documentclass{article}

\NewDocumentCommand\testone{e_}{\mathsf{test}\sb{1\IfValueT{#1}{,#1}}}
\NewDocumentCommand\testtwo{e{_^}}
  {\mathsf{test}\sb{1\IfValueT{#1}{,#1}}\sp{2\IfValueT{#2}{,#2}}}

\begin{document}
$\testone,\testone_2,{\testone}_1$

$\testtwo,\testtwo_2,{\testtwo}_1,\testtwo^1,{\testtwo}^1,\testtwo^1_2$
\end{document}



Thank you! This is perfectly working
